# VB.NET How to copy the application's executable file to another path?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm new to VB.NET and I'm trying to experiment with it. So when the user clicks a button from the application, the executable file should copy itself to a specific path.

So, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not recommended but possible - think about why in the earth you want to do that. A software is not just an EXE.

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim FileToCopy As String
    Dim NewCopy As String
    FileToCopy = Application.StartupPath.ToString & "\WindowsApplication1.exe"
    NewCopy = "D:\_working\WindowsApplication1.exe.copied"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(FileToCopy) = True Then
      System.IO.File.Copy(FileToCopy, NewCopy)
      MessageBox.Show("File Copied")
    End If

  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above is flawed if you are speaking about getting your own assembly in Visual Studios to copy itself to a given path. I tested the following code and it worked without error. Please note the path will have to be changed to fit your needs and be sure to use the name of your program, mine was CryLok.exe.

**Reference:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location?view=net-5.0

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim FileToCopy As String
    Dim NewCopy As String
    FileToCopy = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
    NewCopy = "C:\Users\your name\Desktop\CryLok.exe" 
    If File.Exists(FileToCopy) = True Then
        File.Copy(FileToCopy, NewCopy)
        MessageBox.Show("File Copied")
    End If
End Sub
```